# Get records where no column is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, null

I've a table with 100+ (nullable) columns and 10,000+ rows. I'd like to fetch rows that have no columns null.

```
id|f001|f002|f003|....f100
1 |null|aa  | ss |sada
2 |sdad|aa  | ss |sada
3 |as  |aa  | ss |sada
4 |null|null| ss |sada
```

In above case, only rows with ID 2 and 3 should be the output.

I cannot use cursor nor can I specify the column names individually.

PK is of course ID. It is legacy code and almost the entire application depends on it - can't do anything about the table design.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)
Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> 
(Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate for the time being because the question only says what you cannot do, not what solution elements would be acceptable. The linked Q & A contains examples of most standard solutions to this problem including dynamic SQL and XML methods. Adapting "any column is null" to "no column is null" is usually straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to build dynamically a statement, which (based on the data in the question) is like the following sample code:

```
SELECT id 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT v.f 
   FROM (VALUES 
     (CASE WHEN [f001] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END), 
     (CASE WHEN [f002] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END), 
     (CASE WHEN [f003] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END), 
     (CASE WHEN [f100] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
   ) v (f) 
   WHERE v.f IS NULL
)
```

The whole statement uses the information from the system catalaog views:

```
-- Dynamic statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)

-- All columns, except "id"
SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT CONCAT(N', (CASE WHEN ', QUOTENAME(col.[name]), N' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)')
    FROM sys.columns col
    JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    WHERE (tab.[name] = N'YourTable') AND (sch.[name] = N'dbo') AND (col.[name] <> N'id')
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

-- Final statement
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT id FROM YourTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT v.f FROM (VALUES ',
    STUFF(@stm, 1, 2, N''),
    N') v (f) WHERE v.f IS NULL)'
)

-- Print and execute the statement
PRINT @stm
DECLARE @err int
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err <> 0 PRINT 'Error'
```